# How can I estimate this second order differential equation?. $ \ ((y'(x))^2+1)^{3/2}\cos(x) = y''(x) \ \ ,y(0)=0, y'(0)=1 \ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curvature

$$
\ ((y'(x))^2+1)^{3/2}\cos(x) = y''(x) \
\ ,y(0)=0, y'(0)=1 \
$$
where do I start?.
I know using the Maclaurin series.
what should I use an infinite product or infinite sum.
it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$((y'(x))^2+1)^{3/2}\cos(x) = y''(x) $$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx} y'(x)=((y'(x))^2+1)^{3/2}\cos(x)$$
$$\implies \frac{d~(y'(x))}{(y'(x))^2+1)^{3/2}} =\cos(x)~ dx$$
Putting $~y'=\tan u~$ and then integrating we have
$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y'~^2+1}}= \sin x ~+c\qquad \text{where $~c~$ is a constant}$$
$$\implies y'~^2=(\sin x +c)^2~(y'~^2+1)$$
$$\implies y'~=\frac{\sin x +c}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x +c)^2}}$$
$$\implies y=k+\int \frac{\sin x +c}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x +c)^2}}~dx \qquad \text{where $~c~$and$~k~$ are constants}$$